# Bash process substitution in Python with subprocess.run() and shared input

Tags: python, bash

I have a question regarding bash process substitution in python using subprocess. I'm trying to write it in a way that both the main function and the subprocess use the same input from stdin (which in the code is a string variable). Here is the code:

```
p1 = subprocess.run(['cat'],
     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, input=in_fa.encode())
p2 = subprocess.run(['bwa samse reference/C57BL_6J.fa <(bwa aln -l 20 reference/C57BL_6J.fa -) -'],
     shell=True, executable="/bin/bash", input=p1.stdout,
     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

In this example, `in_fa` is a string like the following:

```
 >header\ntTCAGCCTTCCCTTCCATTTCTCTCCCCTTCCCTCTCCTCCCCATTTCAGAGTTTCTTTAGAATCTGTATTCTGGCACCCAAAGTGAACTATGTGTCTGACTCAGGGGCTCTTTGTTTCACTGCAGGGCTGTGGTG
```

In this code, both '-' in the main process and the subprocess refer to `in_fa`, but while the main process is reading it correctly, the subprocess is not.

This, for example, would work, but it's not dynamic and it's reading from a file instead than a variable:

```
p1 = subprocess.run(['''cat fasta/input.fasta |
    bwa samse reference/C57BL_6J.fa <(
        cat fasta/input.fasta |
          bwa aln -l 20 reference/C57BL_6J.fa -) -'],
    shell=True, executable="/bin/bash", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Any help would be appreciated! Meanwhile, I will keep trying.

Comment: You appear to have a race condition, with two commands in `p2` both trying to read from the same standard input. Also, what is the point of `p1`, instead of using `in_fa.encode()` as the input to `p2` directly?

Comment: I broke up your code for legibility; these long one-liners are disappearing into the right margin on the desktop version of this site, though they look fine on mobile.

Comment: You are right, using 'cat' and 'p1' was just a very bad practice, totally redundant. I still have many things to fix in my coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot consume standard input from two distinct processes; they need to receive a copy each.

My approach to this would be to write the string to a temporary file and take it from there.

In addition, your `subprocess` calls have a couple of problems.

- You need to pass in *either* a string or a list of tokens.  What you have looks like it's working, but it's really not well-defined.
- The `cat` performs no useful purpose here; the purpose of `cat` is to combine multiple files, and you only have one file. ([It wasn't useful in the shell either.](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat))

```
import tempfile
import os

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdirname:
    fa_tmp = os.path.join([tmpdirname, 'in.fa'])
    with open(fa_tmp, 'wb') as handle:
         handle.write(in_fa.encode())
    proc = subprocess.run(
         '''bwa samse reference/C57BL_6J.fa <(
              bwa aln -l 20 reference/C57BL_6J.fa {0})
              {0}'''.format(fa_tmp),
        shell=True, executable="/bin/bash", 
        check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

See also [Running Bash commands in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538) where I have an answer which outlines some of the problems you are having in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was hoping that two processes could read from the same input and avoid creating a temporary file. I will implement your solution instead.

Comment: I added `check=True` but this could still fail silently if the process substitution (the stuff in `<(...)`) has an error.